# Source and/or combinatorial interpretation for $F_{n+k} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i}F_{n-i}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

Through some fussing with Taylor's Theorem in the discrete calculus described [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/pedagogy/pechakucha/) (among other places), I found what I believe to be an identity:

$$F_{n+k} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i}F_{n-i}$$

For example, with $n = 3$ and $k = 3$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_6 &= 8\\
&= \binom{3}{0}F_3 + \binom{3}{1}F_2 + \binom{3}{2}F_1 + \binom{3}{3}F_0\\
&= F_3 + 3F_2 + 3F_1 + F_0\\
&= 2 + 3(1) + 3(1) + 0\\
\end{aligned}
$$

and with $n = 4$ and $k = 2$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
F_6 &= 8\\
&= \binom{2}{0}F_4 + \binom{2}{1}F_3 + \binom{2}{2}F_2\\
&= F_4 + 2F_3 + F_2\\
&= 3 + 2(2) + 1\\
\end{aligned}
$$

I'd like to find a source/alternate proof, but I don't know how to search for this kind of thing, beyond googling "Fibonacci binomial identity" which hasn't so far been successful.

I know there are an insane number of Fibonacci identities out there; is this a special case of something else?

Also, is there a nice combinatorial interpretation?

Comment: cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112752/

Comment: @GrigoryM: Cool -- this is the case where $n = k$, it looks like?

Comment: see (50) in [Fibonacci Number - mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explicit formula for Fibonacci numbers gives:
$$ F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\sigma^n-\overline{\sigma}^n\right) $$
where $\sigma,\overline{\sigma}$ are solutions of $x^2=1+x$. By the binomial theorem it follows that:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}F_{n-i} = F_{n+k}. \tag{1}$$
On the other hand, the LHS of $(1)$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product between $(1+x)^k$ and the generating function of Fibonacci numbers:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}F_{n-i} = [x^n]\frac{x(1+x)^k}{1-x-x^2}&=&[x^{n+k}]\frac{x(x+x^2)^k}{1-x-x^2}\\&=&[x^{n+k}]\frac{x\left(1-(1-x-x^2)\right)^k}{1-x-x^2}\\&=&[x^{n+k}]\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=F_{n+k}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit in the first part? How does it follow from the binomial theorem exactly? Are we substituting in $n - i$ for $n$?

Comment: @EliRose: $$\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\sigma^{n-i} = \sigma^n\left(1-\frac{1}{\sigma}\right)^k = \sigma^n (1+\overline{\sigma})^k = \sigma^n \overline{\sigma}^{2k}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof that does not use generating functions but rather elementary methods, that is, mathematical induction over $k$.

For $k=0$, it's just $F_n=F_n$ which is quite true..

For $k=1$, it's $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ which is true by the definition of the Fibonacci Numbers.

Let's proceed to the induction step.
Assume we proved it for some $k$ and for $k-1$.
Then, using the well-known $\binom{a}{b}=\binom{a-1}{b}+\binom{a-1}{b-1}$ and $\binom{k}{-1}=\binom{k}{k+1}=0$ we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{i} F_{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} \left(\binom{k}{i}+\binom{k}{i-1} \right) F_{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} \binom{k}{i} F_{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} \binom{k}{i-1} F_{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} F_{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} F_{n-1-i}$$
But now we can evoke the induction hypothesis and hence obtain
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{i} F_{n-i}=F_{n+k}+F_{n+k-1}=F_{n+k+1}$$

Thus, we proved the induction step and hence established the result for all possible $n,k$.