# What is a combinatorial proof for the Fibonacci identity $F^2_{n+1} - F^2_{n-1} = F_{2n}$?

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

I've been working on this problem for a while, trying to break it down in terms of the number of ways you can fill a board with squares and dominoes.

I know that for the similar identity $F^2_{n} + F^2_{n-1} = F_{2n-1}$, you can construct a $1 \times2n$ board where you can count it one way as just $F_{2n}$, and the other way you can count it by splitting the board into 2 $1 \times n$ boards, where you can add together all the possible ways you can fill each half assuming a square in the center ($F^2_{n}$), or assuming a domino in the center ($F^2_{n-1}$).

But for this identity, I don't know how to intutively explain taking away the options of a $F^2_{n-1}$ from the options of a $F^2_{n+1}$ board to get the options for a $F_{2n}$ board.

Comment: I can't believe I've never heard of this identity. That seems really surprising to me.

Comment: Just a suggestion, maybe you want to rearrange the identity to be $F_{2n} +F_{n-1}^2 = F_{n+1}^2$? Then at least you are adding options, not taking away.

Comment: We should have $F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2 = F_{2n-1}$ instead. Using this twice we would obtain your identity, but perhaps a combinatorial proof will require *a bit* more work.

Comment: @player3236 could you explain what you mean by using it twice?

Comment: $(F_{n+1}^2 + F_n^2)-(F_n^2 + F_{n-1}^2) = F_{2n+1} - F_{2n-1}$

Comment: Here is a combinatorial interpretation of $F_{2n}$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112752/prove-binomn0f-0-binomn1f-1-binomn2f-2-cdots-binomnnf-n-f

Comment: @Vectorizer this is the same interpretation of $F_n$ that the OP is using.  1 step = square, and 2 steps = domino

Answer (score 3):

This is Identity 14 in *Proofs that Really Count: The Art of Combinatorial Proof*.  The hint is:

> Count the number of pairs of $n$-tilings where at least one ends in a
> square. Condition on whether the first tiling ends in a square or not.

Comment: Do we need to explain what an $n$-tiling is in this answer?  Or is it broadly understood?

Comment: It is the same tiling mentioned in the question: $1 \times n$ board with squares and dominoes.